# PHPUnit: Trying to @cover or @use not existing method

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm learning how to unit test with PHPUnit 4.3.5 / PHP 5.5.14. All went fine until I tried to get my code coverage.  I'm receiving this error: "Trying to @cover or @use not existing method "MyClass::__construct" when trying to get code coverage. I tried other SO answers but couldn't fix it.  Any ideas what am i doing wrong? Thanks!

```
/**
 * Test constructor.
 * @covers MyClass::__construct
 * @group MyClassTest
 */
public function test_Can_Create_MyClass_Instance() {
    $this->assertInstanceOf('MyClass', $this->_myClass);
}
```

Comment: Does your class really have a __construct method? I've checked and the error only happens when there is no constructor. In that case you can't cover it.

Comment: Yes, MyClass (extends MyBaseClass) has a __construct method in witch I initialise some properties and then call parent::__construct($params); Maybe this has something to do with the problem? MyBaseClass also has its __construct($params) method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your class does implement the `__construct` method, then the problem is that the class itself is not found. Start removing the @covers annotation, and check if the class can be loaded. For example try: `var_dump(class_exists('MyClass'));` inside the test (before the assert that I presume won't pass).

In annotations, and in general when passing your class name as a string, you should always refer to the class using its full namespaced name:

```
\MyClass
\MyNamespace\MyClass
```

Answer (score 16):

You can get the same error if you expect the `@covers` annotation to work with the namespace **use** operator.

The following code will not work:

```php
<?php

namespace MyCompany\MyBundle\Test\UnitTest\Service;

use MyCompany\MyBundle\Service\ClassToTest;

class MyAwesomeTest
{
    /**
     * @covers ClassToTest::someMethod()
     */
    public function testSomeMethod()
    {
        // do your magic
    }
}
```

Smart IDEs like PHPStorm solve the `ClassToTest::someMethod()` annotation if you CTRL+click it but PHPUnit will give you a `Trying to @cover or @use not existing method "ClassToTest::someMethod".` error.

There's a pull request for this here: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/1312

As a work around just use the full class name:

```php
<?php

namespace MyCompany\MyBundle\Test\UnitTest\Service;

use MyCompany\MyBundle\Service\ClassToTest;

class MyAwesomeTest
{
    /**
     * @covers \MyCompany\MyBundle\Service\ClassToTest::someMethod()
     */
    public function testSomeMethod()
    {
        // do your magic
    }
}
```